# TypeDescriptor CanConvertFrom Bug? or i'm doing it wrong?

Tags: c#, system

This is an extension method taken out from http://dnpextensions.codeplex.com/.

I understand that the string "test" isn't a number string...

I understand that the GetConverter(targetType) is of type int...

What I don't understand is why it say it can convert from a string... but it fail...

```
/// <summary>
///     Converts an object to the specified target type or returns the default value.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name = "T"></typeparam>
/// <param name = "value">The value.</param>
/// <param name = "defaultValue">The default value.</param>
/// <returns>The target type</returns>
public static T ConvertTo<T>(this object value, T defaultValue)
{
    if (value != null)
    {
        var targetType = typeof(T);
        var valueType = value.GetType();

        if (valueType == targetType) return (T)value;

        var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(value);
        if (converter != null)
        {
            if (converter.CanConvertTo(targetType))
                return (T)converter.ConvertTo(value, targetType);
        }

        converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(targetType);
        if (converter != null)
        {
            if (converter.CanConvertFrom(valueType))
                return (T)converter.ConvertFrom(value);
        }
    }
    return defaultValue;
}
```

---

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestConvertToWillFail()
    {
        // Arrange
        var value = "test";

        // Act
        var result = value.ConvertTo<int>();

        // Assert
        result.Should().Equal(0);
        result.Should().Not.Equal(value);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestConvertToShouldPass()
    {
        // Arrange
        var value = 123;
        var stringValue = "123";

        // Act
        var stringResult = stringValue.ConvertTo<int>();

        // Assert
        stringResult.Should().Equal(value);
        stringResult.Should().Not.Equal(0);
    }
```

Note: Should() is from Should.codeplex.com

---

Exception from test:

> test is not a valid value for Int32.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What your method is doing in the second call is:

- Get the StringConverter
- Ask it if it can convert to integers - it answers **no**
- Get the IntegerConverter
- Ask it if it can convert from string - it answers **yes**
- Ask it to convert the provided value ("test") - and this is where it blows up, since "test" is indeed not a valid value for Int32.

The `CanConvertFrom/To` methods are just to verify if the call makes sense at all, not whether the conversion will succeed, since `CanConvert` works only on the type level

There are strings that will convert to valid integers, but that does not mean that all strings are valid integers, so `ConvertFrom/To` will throw exceptions, even if the `CanConvert` return true.

Answer (score 1):

This is my work around.
Please let me know if there's a better version of this out there.

```
/// <summary>
///     Converts an object to the specified target type or returns the default value.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name = "T"></typeparam>
/// <param name = "value">The value.</param>
/// <param name = "defaultValue">The default value.</param>
/// <returns>The target type</returns>
public static T ConvertTo<T>(this object value, T defaultValue)
{
    if (value != null)
    {
        try
        {
            var targetType = typeof(T);
            var valueType = value.GetType();

            if (valueType == targetType)
                return (T)value;

            var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(value);
            if (converter != null)
            {
                if (converter.CanConvertTo(targetType))
                    return (T)converter.ConvertTo(value, targetType);
            }

            converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(targetType);
            if (converter != null)
            {
                if (converter.CanConvertFrom(valueType))
                {

                    return (T)converter.ConvertFrom(value);

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return defaultValue;
        }
    }
    return defaultValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ConvertTo [can throw exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13battt.aspx) if it is not able to perform the conversion... even if CanConvertTo returns true.

e.g. "12" can be converted to an integer but "test" cannot be. However the converter would say that it **can convert** from string to integer.

Comment: Actually I just find out that the StringConverter does not convert to integers, but the IntegerConverter converts from strings. A bit odd, but that's how it goes.

Comment: @SWeko: Interestingly, the `StringConverter` can only convert to and from strings  ;P